# Issue in using "HAL_UART_Transmit" in FreeRTOS-MPU Usermode (Non-Priviledge) task on STM32F412

Tags: stm32, freertos, cortex-m, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I am using the FreeRTOS-MPU port with STM32F412 to achieve memory protection. I have successfully made both tasks **UserMode**(Non-Privilege) and **PrivilegeMode**. But I am not able to run the "*HAL_UART_Transmit*" API (or similar HAL APIs)in UserMode which result in Memory Fault. However, the same API is working properly in the **Privilege** mode tasks.

Does anyone have idea What am I missing?

My Project Linker Scrip is as below which is taken from STM32F4 SDK FreeRTOS_MPU project example:

```
/*
******************************************************************************
**
**  File        : LinkerScript.ld
**
**  Author      : Auto-generated by Ac6 System Workbench
**
**  Abstract    : Linker script for STM32F412CGUx series
**                1024Kbytes FLASH and 256Kbytes RAM
**
**                Set heap size, stack size and stack location according
**                to application requirements.
**
**                Set memory bank area and size if external memory is used.
**
**  Target      : STMicroelectronics STM32
**
**  Distribution: The file is distributed “as is,” without any warranty
**                of any kind.
**
*****************************************************************************

/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x20040000;    /* end of RAM */
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
FLASH_priv (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 16K
FLASH (rx)         : ORIGIN = 0x08004000, LENGTH = 1008K
RAM_priv (xrw)     : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 2048
RAM (xrw)          : ORIGIN = 0x20000800, LENGTH = 254K
}

/* Variables used by FreeRTOS-MPU. */
_Privileged_Functions_Region_Size = 16K;
_Privileged_Data_Region_Size     = 2048;

__FLASH_segment_start__        = ORIGIN( FLASH_priv );
__FLASH_segment_end__          = __FLASH_segment_start__ + LENGTH( FLASH_priv ) + LENGTH( FLASH );

__privileged_functions_start__ = ORIGIN( FLASH_priv );
__privileged_functions_end__   = __privileged_functions_start__ + _Privileged_Functions_Region_Size;

__SRAM_segment_start__         = ORIGIN( RAM_priv );
__SRAM_segment_end__           = __SRAM_segment_start__ + LENGTH( RAM_priv ) + LENGTH( RAM );

__privileged_data_start__      = ORIGIN( RAM_priv );
__privileged_data_end__        = __privileged_data_start__ + _Privileged_Data_Region_Size;

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH_priv
  .privileged_functions : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(privileged_functions)
    *(privileged_functions*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH_priv

  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH

  .pbss : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _spbss = .;
    *(privileged_data)
    *(privileged_data*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _epbss = .;
  } >RAM_priv 
  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sipdata = LOADADDR(.pdata);
  .pdata : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _spdata = .;
    *(privileged_initialized_data)
    *(privileged_initialized_data*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _epdata = .;
  } >RAM_priv AT> FLASH_priv
  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH


  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >RAM



  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the MPU to allow user mode access to the UART peripheral (and any other peripherals used by the UART driver library.

To start with create an MPU region from address 0x40000000 to 0x60000000 (size:0x20000000) with user mode read write access.

I would recommend adding a MPU fault handler in the vector table so you know when you get an error.

Comment: creating an MPU region from address 0x40000000 to 0x60000000 (size:0x20000000) with user mode read write access didn't worked. But if i use RAM address (in my case 0x20000800) and sized upto 254KB than it worked. If this is the solution than there is no meaning of use of MPU ?